# Restricting image inside div and arrange those div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Gridster for webpage.The widgets have images on it.These images can be added and deleted with `+` and `X` button.

On clicking  `+`, a modal opens and displays images which I retrieve from server dynamically

The modal is the `<div1 class="modal-body">`.In that I want `<div2 class="outerdiv">`.

In a single row in `div1` there should be an equal number of `div2` is what I want.Entire `div1` should have `div2` which are separated properly from each other and same in number on each row.

Then comes `<div3 class="innerdiv">` which will be inside each `div2.The`div3`  will contain my image which should fit properly within that div only.

Overall, when I open my modal the images should symmetrically and properly placed from each other

The CSS which I tried

```
.modal-body {
  width: 100%;

  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

.outerdiv {
  height: 90px;
  width: 90px;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}


.innerdiv{
max-height:95%;
max-width:95%;


}
```

My actual code for server

```
<div class="modal-body">

            {% for file in brands %}
            {% load static %}
            <div class="outerdiv"><div class="innerdiv"><img src="{% get_static_prefix %}images/brands/{{file}}"></div></div>
            {% endfor %}      

    </div>
```

My representational image:

```
<div class="outerdiv"><div class="innerdiv"><img src="https://cdnd.icons8.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Run-Command-100.png"></div></div>
```

I dont know if what I did is right or not because when I when I do inspect element in browser I see that image is coming out of the div also sometimes the images almost overlap each other

Jquery function which applies `preset class` to clicked image.I want it to be applied to `innverdiv`

```
var parentLI;
$(document).on("click", ".addmorebrands", function() {
                parentLI = $(this).closest('li');
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
            $('#exampleModalCenter img').click(function(){
        $(this).addClass('preselect');
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('preselect');
        selectedImageSRC = $(this).attr('src');
      })
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tfq1m9L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `preselect` class to the `innerdiv`.

Make some of these css modifications:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.preselect{
  background: lightgreen;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

checkout [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tfq1m9L/32/)